# How do I "expect" before block to change something in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a test suite structured this way:

```
let(:cat) { create :blue_russian_cat } 
subject { cat }

context "empty bowl" do
  let!(:bowl) { create(:big_bowl, amount: 0) }
  before { meow }

  # a ton of `its` or `it` which require `meow` to be executed before making assertion
  its(:status) { should == :annoyed }
  its(:tail) { should == :straight }
  # ...

  # here I want to expect that number of PetFishes is going down after `meow`, like that
  it "will eat some pet fishes" do
    expect {???}.to change(PetFish, :count).by(-1)
  end
end
```

Usually I would just place this block outside of context calling `expect` like that:

```
  it "will eat some pet fishes" do
    expect { meow }.to change(PetFish, :count).by(-1)
  end
```

But it makes code a bit harder to read, since related code are placed outside of its context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you consider changing both your tests to `expect` syntax to get them under the same `context`?  Perhaps something like:

```
let(:cat) { create :blue_russian_cat } 

context "empty bowl" do
  let!(:bowl) { create(:big_bowl, amount: 0) }
  let(:meowing) { -> { meow } } # not sure what meow is, so may not need lambda

  it "will annoy the cat" do
    expect(meowing).to change(cat.status).from(:placid).to(:annoyed)
  end

  # here I want to expect that number of PetFishes is going down after `meow`
  it "will eat some pet fishes" do
    expect(meowing).to change(PetFish, :count).by(-1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting idea, although rewriting all tests in `expect` manner seem to be cumbersome.

Comment: @Andrew I does take a while if you have a lot of tests, but I think it would be worth it in the long run as it seems that `expect` syntax will be [the default syntax for RSpec moving forward](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax) and is [recommended for new projects](http://branch.com/b/which-rspec-syntax-do-you-prefer).  But, this is mostly a matter of your syntactical taste and preferences.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `expect(meowing.call)` seeing as meowing is a lambda?

Answer (score 3):

You don't set expectations on `before` block. Its purpose is to set up the environment (and also it's executed *before* the spec, so it's too late to expect something of it). You want regular `let`.

```
context "empty bowl" do
  let(:cat) { meow }

  # here I want to expect that number of PetFishes is going down after `meow`, like that
  it "will eat some pet fishes" do
    expect {cat}.to change(PetFish, :count).by(-1)
  end
end
```

Comment: So, no way to put both of them under the same context?

Comment: I have some context under which I want to execute number of specs, most of them require `meow` to be called before making assertion, but there are few which have `expect` in them, so I can either call `before { meow }` or put `meow` invocation inside each case, the latter one seem to be a bad idea.

Comment: Well, in any case, how do you think it's possible to expect something of code that runs **before** the spec? It can't be done, by definition. So, take the ugly path.

Answer (score 0):

I realise that using instance variables is less than ideal but if your sensibilities allow it, you could do this:

```
context "empty bowl" do
  # ...
  before { @pet_fish_change = change_to(PetFish, :count) {meow} }

  it "will eat some pet fishes" do
    expect(@pet_fish_change).to eq(-1)
  end

  # ...

end
```

Which requires that you define a `change_to` helper method but that's really simple:

```
def change_to(obj, method, &block)
  before = obj.send method
  yield
  (obj.send method) - before
end
```